# How to display a ForeignKey field in a ModelForm with no default value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I need to create a form for `Player` that has `Role` objects as choices in a dropdown field, but with their string field shown instead.

`models.py`

```
class Player(models.Model):
    role = models.ForeignKey(role)
    ...

class Role(models.Model):
    designation = models.CharField()
```

`forms.py`

```
class PlayerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ['role']
```

Say I have three `role` objects with these as their `designation`s, respectively: `Warrior`, `Mage`, `Rouge`, how can I display it in a `PlayerForm` instance as a dropdown, with *no* default value so the user *has* to choose one?

Currently this code displays the objects as the objects themselves (`Role object (1)`, `Role object (2)`, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is mainly an issue with rendering the objects. You can define a `__str__` method to specify how the `Role`s should be rendered:

```
class Role(models.Model):
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.designation
```

You also might want to set the `designation` to a `unique=True` field, to prevent defining two `Role`s with the same `designation`.

Comment: do I have to define it as `__str__`, and not something else? how would I account in the code if I need some other field to be displayed instead?

Comment: @mashedpotatoes: you return the other field in the `__str__` (or string interpolation of several fields).

Comment: There is still the part that there should be no default value. The dropdown still shows `------` and while this can be solved by adding `role_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(Role.objects.all(), empty_label=None)` in the form above the `Meta` class declaration, it queries `Role` objects. Is there a better way, or this would do/ or there's no other way around it?

Comment: @mashedpotatoes: well this is the option that specifies that you did not select a value yet. If you would submit the form with `----`, the form will reject it, since that means you did not select a value. You can specify a default value, bit since you do not want to do that, then what value should it select in the dropdown initially?

Answer (score 2):

add

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.designation
```

to your `Role` class and all your choices become real names)